# How to treat a randomly generated Date as UTC time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc, moment-timezone

Using the [moment-random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-random) library, I am trying to generate a Date between `2021-02-10 00:00:00` and `2021-02-10 23:59:59` and then create a `Date` object.

Although I am still trying to understand how this works internally, I think it is using my local  timezone prior to creating the Date obj, which results in Date objects being outside of the range I specified.

Example:

```
let random = momentRandom(
  moment().tz("UTC").format("2021-02-10 23:59:59"),
  moment().tz("UTC").format("2021-02-10 00:00:00")
).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(random);
console.log(new Date(random))
```

From the code above, I can get the following results (all within the range)

```
2021-02-10 16:30:38
2021-02-10T21:30:38.000Z
```

```
2021-02-10 05:08:59
2021-02-10T10:08:59.000Z
```

But eventually, if I keep generating Dates, the Date obj may go out of the range based on the value generated randomly.

```
2021-02-10 21:54:58
2021-02-11T02:54:58.000Z <-- outside the range [2021-02-10 00:00:00, 2021-02-10 23:59:59]
```

Is there anyway I can use the random value as UTC and let the `Date` constructor treat that as UTC? Thanks

For example, a desired output:

```
2021-02-10 05:08:59
2021-02-10T05:08:59.000Z
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I can get the results I am expecting by just appending "Z" to the generated value as such:

`console.log(new Date(random + "Z"));`

However, I am still wondering what that does and what's happening behind the scenes. A response would still be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment().tz("UTC").format("2021-02-10 23:59:59")` is simply going to return "2021-02-10 23:59:59", always.

`moment()` creates a moment for "now", [*format*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) expects a set of formatting tokens but the above gives it a string containing no tokens, so it just returns the string (which does not contain a timezone offset so is treated as local).

What you seem to want to do is parse "2021-02-10 23:59:59" as UTC, so use the [*utc* method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) when parsing the timestamp, not when formatting (because once it's parsed as local, it's too late to change it to UTC):

```js
console.log( moment.utc('2021-02-10 23:59:59').format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The default output from *format* is ISO 8601 so you don't need to provide any tokens and your expression can be:

```
let ramdon = momentRandom(
  moment.utc("2021-02-10 23:59:59").format(),
  moment.utc("2021-02-10 00:00:00").format()
).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

However, that seems a long winded way of changing "2021-02-10 23:59:59" to "2021-02-10T23:59:59Z" when simple string manipulation will have exactly the same result:

```
"2021-02-10 23:59:59".replace(' ','T') + 'Z'
```

Comment: `momentRandom(end, start)` takes whatever you can pass into `moment()`. So I would suggest passing actual dates (or moments) that are in the range you want, rather than strings.

Comment: @HereticMonkey—I don't see any point in parsing a string using *moment.js* only to pass the result to *momentRandom*, when *momentRandom* is going to parse it exactly the same way. But that's up to the OP of course. :-)

Comment: I just tested this but calling the `utc()` method before `format()` does not solve the issue, unless I keep the 'Z' when creating the Date object as such `new Date(ramdon + "Z")`. I guess this means that *momentRandom* keeps converting to local and the Date constructor is needing that `Z` to understand that I want to treat `random` as UTC?

Comment: @chris The problem you're having is that you're using an ambiguous format for `random`. If you want a `Date` object, use Moment's `toDate()` method; don't serialize it to a string, then back to a `Date`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey— "2021-02-10T23:59:59Z" isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @chris— `new Date(ramdon + "Z")` will produce an invalid date in some implementations, don't use it, the "T" is important. `moment.utc("2021-02-10 23:59:59").format()` produces "2021-02-10T23:59:59Z", that will be parsed as UTC by moment.js (and the built–in parser). If it's not treated as UTC by *momentRandom*, your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @RobG not sure why I kept thinking that wasn't solving the problem. I tested one more time and it definitely works. Thanks, I am accepting your answer :)

Comment: @RobG True, but from the OP, and your answer, `random` is a string, generated using `format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")` after the `momentRandom` call, which is ambiguous. If `random` is meant to be used as a `Date` object, the OP is better served by using `toDate()`, to preserve the value as a `Date`, or leaving `format` off and using the Moment object itself.  I'm not sure why you appear to think I'm disagreeing with you. I'm attempting to enhance your answer by advising the OP on what to do with the output of `momentRandom`, rather than the input (which your answer does well).

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, I definitely replaced `format()` with `toDate()` too which makes it work better, thanks!